# Error with Hibernate JPQL IN Query: No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5.Final, Postgresql 9.3-1101-jdbc41 and GlassFish 4. I want to write a JPQL query that selects all message threads that contain user1 and user2. The participating users in a message thread are stored in an ArrayList participants.

With this query:

```
ArrayList<UserBean> users = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(user1, user2));
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT mt FROM MessageThreadBean mt WHERE mt.participants IN (:users)");
        query.setParameter("users", users);
```

I get this error:

```
WARN:   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22023
ERROR:   No value specified for parameter 1.
Info:   HHH000106: Forcing container resource cleanup on transaction completion
Severe:   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.QueryWrapper.getResultList(QueryWrapper.java:84)
at com.dobe.hobbyleague.backingbeans.RightSideBarBackingBean.selectUserLoadThreads(RightSideBarBackingBean.java:78)
at com.dobe.hobbyleague.backingbeans.RightSideBarBackingBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.selectUserLoadThreads(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:41)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:268)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:135)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
... 72 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.checkAllParametersSet(SimpleParameterList.java:216)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:244)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
... 88 more
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find by id:

```
ArrayList<Long> users = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(user1.getId(), user2.getId()));
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM MessageThreadBean mt WHERE mt.participants.id IN (:users)");
query.setParameter("users", users);
```

**UPDATE**

In case you get an error, try to join both tables:

```
"FROM MessageThreadBean mt INNER JOIN mt.participants p WHERE p.id IN (:users)"
```

Comment: Using your approach I get this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [messagethr0_.id.participants] with element property reference [id] [SELECT mt FROM com.dobe.hobbyleague.messagethread.MessageThreadBean mt WHERE mt.participants.id IN (:users)]

Comment: I've updated my answer so you can see how to use an inner join in your query

Comment: The query runs now, but there are still problems:
1: It returns twice the number of results it should (I think that is because it returns one match for user1 and then another for user 2) - 
2: The results in the list are type Object, not MessageThreadBean. Also, I heard that you should avoid joins because of performance issues. Any other ideas?

Comment: You must rewrite your query in the way you need, and cast it to your required type

Comment: I tried casting it, but I get an error that I cannot cast type Object to type MessageThreadBean.

Comment: Have you tried casting it in [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/905974/2982518)?

Comment: I was lazy and just copied the query, without realising you omitted  the SELECT bit at the beginning. I also added DISTINCT to not get duplicate results. The final query is: SELECT DISTINCT mt FROM MessageThreadBean mt INNER JOIN mt.participants p WHERE p IN (:users)  Thanks for your help Genzotto!