# cast List<Row> to List<T> in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am picking values from cassandra table and storing them in dataset like this:

```
Dataset query =spark.sql("select url,sourceip,destinationip from traffic_data");
List<Row> = query.collectAsList();
```

now i have a POJO class GroupClass having variables as url,sourceip and destionationip.

```
Is it possible to cast this List<Row> to List<GroupClass>?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast generic List types in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905964/how-to-cast-generic-list-types-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can, but this will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

The best practice, in this case, is to use a [Copy Constructor](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-java/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from scala but I do believe that there's a similar way in java.

A possible solution whould be the following :

```
val query =spark.sql("select url,sourceip,destinationip from traffic_data").as[GroupClass]
```

Now the query value has the type `Dataset[GroupClass]`, so calling `collectAsList()` method retruns a List[GroupClass]

```
val list = query.collectAsList();
```

Another solution (I think you have to use `streams` to do the same thing in java) is to `map` each `Row` from list in a `GroupClass` like this :

```
val query =spark.sql("select url,sourceip,destinationip from traffic_data")
val list = query.collectAsList();
val mappedList = list.map {
  case Row(url: String,sourceip: String,destinationip: String) => 
  GroupClass(url, sourceip, destinationip)
}
```

I considered that all the attributes (url, sourceip, destinationip) has a `String`

you have to create the `GroupedClass` :

```
GroupClass(url: String,sourceip: String,destinationip: String)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: if you're using the code above, it will absolutely show as error because as I said above this code is for scala. anyway, share this error so that we can help you !!

Answer (score 0):

you should use Encoders for this

```
Dataset schools = context
.read()
.json("/schools.json")
.as(Encoders.bean(University.class));
```

more info can be found here https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html
or here https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-Encoder.html